# Decision Table-Loop through the Objects with specific property match

Tags: syntax, drools

I am trying to loop through the list of objects and collect a specific property on the object and match with list of entries in decision table, I tried some combination of accumulate and collect, But always it throws an error on compile, Not sure what is the issue.

The final property will be a string match on the condition column.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The rule will be as below, But it always shows mismatch input '==', Not sure why.I also need to compare a empty string out of it.